# Put SQL query within string with parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net

Have some problems to place long sql query to command but i always have some problem - can you help me out with it?

This is my query i want to put within `cmd` with two parameters `newvalue` and `oldvalue`

query itself:

```
    UPDATE tbElemPics
    SET    PicturePath = Stuff(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                                          + 1, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                                                                          + 1) - Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1, 'newvalue')
    WHERE  Substring(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                                 + 1, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                                                                 + 1) - Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1) = 'oldvalue'
```

And method with cmd where above sql should be placed with two parameters:

```
 Public Sub ChangeMachineNames(OldMachName As String, NewMachName As String)
        Dim strcon = New AppSettingsReader().GetValue("ConnectionString", GetType(System.String)).ToString()
        Using con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("here i want to put my sql", con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newvalue", NewMachName)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldvalue", OldMachName)
                con.Open()
                Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you explain what type of query you want to generate, probably you may get some more answers, may be new approach to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in a variable and then assign that variable to Command

```
Dim strCmd As String = ""
strCmd &= " UPDATE tbElemPics"
strCmd &= " SET    PicturePath = Stuff(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)"
strCmd &= " + 1, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)"
strCmd &= " + 1) - Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1, @newvalue)"
strCmd &= " WHERE  Substring(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)"
strCmd &= " + 1, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)"
strCmd &= " + 1) - Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1) = @oldvalue"


Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strCmd, con)
```

Comment: hi you sure there is no typo ? ^^

Comment: sorry... i updated my main post - how to change also your string to pass those two parameters - i marked them within query

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to do here. It seems you are updating some paths stored in the database. Check your brackets. But the way to provide parameters is this. Put `@` sign before your param name and without quotes `( ' )`

Comment: exactly i want to pass two values into this query using parameters. Can you assure me its fine formatted? ^^

Comment: The way to use parameters is with `@` but I have not tested it with Stuff function.

Comment: seems its ok like you posted - thx marked as answer. If you could just take a look last time as i am putting it to production would be apreaciated and give me feedback :)

Comment: sorry one more thing i forgot to mention i got something like that at the end of my query:   ) = N'oldvalue'    - as you see there additional N  , can i just put it into the string no more chars are needed for that means like this is enough?:  = N@oldvalue"

Comment: No need to put this additional N, you can just use it as = @oldValue, N is just a SQL Server way to explicitly mark a value as String. And regarding parameters in stuff: it should work as described here http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=3934817c-1a03-4ac9-a0ba-55b2bfbaea0f&tkw=uses-of-the-stuff-string-function

Comment: i need it because if specific chars appear e.g ą ę ż etc.. then i need instead of    = 'oldvalue'     = N'oldvalue'       . What will be the diffrence in case of our string to attach this N?

Comment: Any values passed using parameters are automatically converted to the relevant column type. i.e. if column type is date, int, nvarchar then @param will be automatically converted to date, int and nvarchar respectively. So you need not specify N